# jQuery DataTables altEditor issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been trying to get this free alternative editor I found [here](https://github.com/KasperOlesen/DataTable-AltEditor) to work but it keeps on blowing up on me because I am terrible at javaScript. Been debugging, reading documentations like mad all day but my scrub mind is out of ideas but I'm still trying anyway.

I deleted some of the stuff it had in there like ajax to server,the ID row, because I don't need those, I just want to be able to insert, edit, and delete rows in the table while keeping the `<option>` dropdown and pattern validation.

I prepared a jsfiddle with my exact setup [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/205/). Any hints/help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out myself. 
[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbLjzspf/207/) is an updated version that works. 
[This diff](https://www.diffnow.com/?report=c05ez) shows the modifications I made compared to the original. 
What is the point you ask?
The point is to be able to validate stuff before adding/editing them, to have a neat dropdown select, and to be able to send the data from the table itself as a JSON string in a `"Column Name" : "Cell Data"` format so that I can `json_decode($_POST['table']` and use a nice associative array to add the data to my database. 
Why?
Beats me, do what you want with it. I plan to use it to send a list of addresses one way only to the server. 
Why not use the official editor? 
Because I can't justify the price for my meaningless project and I hardly need 10% of what it offers.

Big thanks to Kingcode.com where I found the free datatables editor alternative and KasperOlesen for making it more awesome.